# Deleting/replacing every nth, mth and ith char from string

Tags: python, python-3.x

What am I doing wrong with deleting/replacing every nth, mth and ith characters of my string?

```
''.join('*' if any(i % n == 0 for n in [9, 10, 11]) 
        else char for i, char in enumerate(string))
```

For:

```
string = "100000000111000000001110000000011"
```

It returns:

```
*00000000***000000*0*1*0000*00*11
```

Instead of:

```
*00000000***00000000***00000000**
```

Comment: The output you see is correct.  Why are you expecting that other output instead?

Comment: Output looks correct to me; indices 9, 18, and 27 (multiples of 9) as well as 10, 20 and 30 (multiples of 10) and 11 and 22 (multiples of 11) are taken out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you expecting `*00000000***00000000***00000000**`? Every 9th, 10th and 11th character would be:

```
9th: 0, 9, 18...
10th: 0, 10, 20...
11th: 0, 11, 22...
Combined: 0, 9, 10, 11, 18, 20, 22...
```

Which would in fact be `*00000000***000000*0*1*0000*00*11` for the provided string. Based on your expected result, it looks like what you actually are wanting it to do is mask out the 1st, 10th and 11th characters (indexes 0, 9 and 10) *for every 11 characters*. Try this instead:

```
>>> ''.join('*' if i % 11 in [0, 9, 10]
...         else char for i, char in enumerate(string))
'*00000000***00000000***00000000**'
```

Comment: something is missing at yours `if` i presume?

Comment: The code I gave works for me. It gives the expected result you posted.